# Positioning a TiKz rectangle centered vertically with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsart

Here is the basic working document I am using:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection} \tikz \fill [orange] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to move the orange rectangle a bit lower so that the imaginary horizontal line running across the center is lined up with the horizontal line of the text. I've tried playing around with the numbers but I can't seem to move it past down that lower text line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection} \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] \fill [orange] (0,0) rectangle (5,1);

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can align the picture using anchors of the bounding box (as in the given example) or you can specify any numeric value for the baseline of the inline picture (as in `baseline=-5ex`).

Comment: Thanks dom, is there a list of what options/values I can specify for the baseline?

Comment: check section 12.2.1 of the manual. Anyway I was referring to numeric values, like `-5ex` and similar. I edited the answes for the sake of clarity.